# How to read hdf5 files from polars?

Tags: hdf5, python-polars

Is there any preferred way to deal with `hdf5` files from `polars`? I cannot find any mention of them in the documentation. Polars seems like a wonderful library, but this is a major issue for me.

Comment: We don't have a `hdf5` reader. Currently going via `pandas` is easiest. We promise to make up for the copy time in downstream code.

I opened an issue for this: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/3520

If you want to read that data often, I would convert it to feather/ipc or parquet. These formats are desired by polars.

Comment: @ritchie46 Thank you! I assume also that if the object one desires to read is a pandas dataframe with a multiindex, the right thing to do is to reset_index, and just use the index as another column in a pl dataframe (or the formats you support...)

Comment: Indeed. We just have columns, no index. We can have nested columns with struct and list types if required.

Comment: Did @ritchie64's comments address your problem? Or do you need help writing code that loads your data from hdf5 file to a pandas df or polars?

Comment: @kcw78 There is no problem reading the data from hdf5 to pandas, as for the polars side, I am not sure what the best practices are - one advantage of hdf5 is that the data is somewhat organized in one file object. Not sure if there is something similar in the parquet/arrow world...

Comment: In my own case I like Polars a lot more than dataframes and imho the parquet/arrow formats are better than hdf5, but not being able to read hdf5 files would make it harder for me to sell it at work as a pandas replacement since hdf5 files are widely used there.

Comment: @saolof Yes, same here, although I do not know enough about parquet/arrow to say if they are better. Why do you think they are?

Answer (score 0):

## Simply load via `pandas` then copy to `polars`

### → using [`pl.from_pandas`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.from_pandas.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl

pd_df = pd.read_hdf("some_file.h5")
pl_df = pl.from_pandas(pd_df)
```